# How avoid I a comparation with NULL in strcmp?

Tags: c, c-strings, string-literals, strcmp, strcpy

I'm tring to make this program work, but after giving it a lot of turns, I decided is time to ask. No matter what I do the result is always a segmentation fault and I pretty much sure that is for the strcmp. Can you help me please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main ()
{
    char *marcas[7] = {"Alfa Romeo", "Fiat", "Ford", "Lancia", "Renaudl", '\0', '\0'};
    char *marca, *aux;
    int i;
    int cont=5;
    
    marca=" ";
    aux=" ";        
    for(i=0;i<cont;i++)
    printf("%s\n",marcas[i]);
    while (cont<7){
    printf("Ingrese la marca que desee agregar a la lista.\n");
    scanf("%s",marca);
    printf("Gracias. Ud. quiere agregar la marca: %s.\n", marca);
    i=0;
    while(strcmp(marcas[i], marca)<0 && i<cont){
            i++;
            printf("Moviendo puntero.\n");
    }
    printf("Termine de mover.\n");
    if (i < cont){
       while (i<cont){
        strcpy(aux,marcas[i]);
        strcpy(marcas[i],marca);
        strcpy(marca,aux);
        i++;
       }
    } 
    printf("%s tiene que ir en la posicion %d\n", marca, i);
    strcpy(marcas[i],marca);    
    cont++;
    for(i=0;i<cont;i++)
        printf("%s\n", marcas[i]);
    printf("La marca ingresada última a la lista:%s\n", marca);
    }
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    printf("%s\n", marcas[i]);
}
```

Comment: The first thing you should always do is enable all the compiler warnings.  For example if you're using GCC, you would add the `-Wall` option to the compile line.  The compiler will give you a wealth of information about bad practices, or even outright errors in your code.

Comment: The last two elements of your array, i.e. `'\0'`, are just very misleading ways of writing `NULL` in that context.  They are not strings, but are integer constants whose value is the null character, i.e. the value zero, which in a pointer context are the `NULL` pointer.  Why are they there?  You can't pass those elements to `strcmp` since they're `NULL` pointers.

Comment: @MadScientist The only warning `gcc -Wall` gives for this code is the incorrect declaration of `main`, which should return `int` rather than `void`.  The `'\0'` constants, while unusual, are simply zero constants which are taken to be `NULL` pointers in that context, with no warning given.

Comment: If I enable -O2 I get more warnings (GCC 13) but I was really surprised to not get any warnings about assigning a constant string to a `char*`.  GCC must allow this as a special case but it seems very dangerous to me to not warn about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program contains many segfaults, due to the fact that c does not have built in variable length strings, as many other programming languages do.
This can cause problems with trying to 'overfill' a string.

```
char *marca, *aux;
```

In this line, you define a pointer (marca and aux) to a single character each, and so when you call this line:

```
scanf("%s",marca);
```

you are reading a potentially huge block of text off the command line, and trying to fit it all into the space of one character. This is not good for the program, and if not dealt with can cause vulnerabilities such as [Buffer Overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). C is an inherently unsafe language, and I recommend learning what you are doing before you attempt to use pointers. A better solution might be something like this:

```
// Create a list of characters (a string) 128 spaces long called marca, and initialize it.
char marca[128] = {'\0'};
char aux[128] = {'\0'};
```

In conclusion, the best course of action would be to learn C properly.

Comment: I know. It make a lot time since I used strings in C and I really forget a lot of things. I must star learning again

Comment: marca and aux aren't pointers to single character; they are *uninitialized* pointers, no memory was reserved with malloc nor they are made to point to some other buffer.

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
scanf("%s",marca);
```

invokes undefined behavior at least because it is trying to change the string literal pointed to by the pointer `marca`

```
marca=" ";
```

You need to declare a character array where you will read a string.

The same problem exists with the pointer `aux` used in calls of `strcpy`

```
strcpy(aux,marcas[i]);
```

and with other string literals that are pointed to by elements of the array `marcas`. SO instead of the array of pointers declare a two-dimensional array initialized by the string literals.

For example

```
char marcas[7][12] = {"Alfa Romeo", "Fiat", "Ford", "Lancia", "Renaudl", };
```

Pay attention to that any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

Comment: I will try this. Cross your fingers, as we say in Argentina.

Comment: @AndreaGraf marca and aux also should be declared as arrays like for example char marca[12]; And a call of scanf will look like scanf( "%11s", marca );

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly!!!! I'm surprised that was so little that make me suffer so much. HAHAHAHAHA

Answer (score 0):

One additional note to the other answers is that you can use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead of `scanf`. The good thing with `fgets` is that you can limit the number of characters read from the user to whatever you want.

So instead of

```
scanf("%s", marca);
```

do

```
fgets(marca, 128 /*or whatever number you choose*/, stdin);
```

The above `fgets` call will only read the first 128 (or whatever number you choose) characters from the user, no matter how many they actually enter. This will prevent buffer overflows.

Comment: Thank you @azhen7, I never used fgets before, but I going to have it in count the next time.